# ParseEther is getting undefined

Tags: ether, hardhat

My Code:

```
const ethers = require("hardhat")

const networkConfig = {
  4: {
    name: "goerli",
    vrfCoordinatorv2: "0x2Ca8E0C643bDe4C2E08ab1fA0da3401AdAD7734D",
    enterenceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),
    gasLane: "0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15",
    subscriptionId: "0",
    callbackGasLimit: "500000",
    interval: "30",
  },
  31337: {
    name: "hardhat",
    entehenceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),
    gasLane: "0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15",
  },
}

const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"]

module.exports = [networkConfig, developmentChains]
```

My Error:

```
Error: ERROR processing skip func of C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\deploy\00-deploy-mocks.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parseEther')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\helper-hardhat-config.js:7:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\deploy\00-deploy-mocks.js:5:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1100:15)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:16)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:669:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
```

Can Someone tell me where I am incorrect? I am not able to figure it out..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the first line of your code:

> `const ethers = require("hardhat")`

You're importing Hardhat as `ethers`, an easy fix would be to do something like

> `const { ethers } = require("hardhat")`

or just call it `hardhat` and use `hardhat.ethers` wherever you're using `ethers` right now.

Comment: Yes, thanks Ziyad

Comment: Feel free to mark this as accepted so it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 8):

function "parseEther" have been migrated from ethers.utils to ethers
.

So when you want to use that in version 6, just use

- `ethers.parseEther("0.05")`

or, you can downgrade your ethers version to 5.
You can look up these docs.

1. [ethers 6 doc](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseEther)
2. [ethers 5 doc](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/utils/#parseEther)

Answer (score 0):

function "parseEther" have been migrated from ethers.utils to ethers .

```
If you are using version 6 so then use ethers.parseEther("0.01") like this.

otherwise, Downgrade your ethers latest version to 5:
```

`yarn add ethers@5.7.2  or npm install ethers@5.7.2`

Comment: Please provide an explanation on why this may fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**you should add below import statement this should work**

`const { parseEther } = require("ethers/lib/utils");`

`const sendValue = parseEther("1")`

Answer (score 0):

now you know most of the function are change
so now we can directly use parseUnits function to change value from ether to wei

```
const {ethers,formatUnits,parseUnits,JsonRpcProvider} =require('ethers');

value: parseUnits('0.01',"ether")
```

you can directly use **parseUnit** for conversion

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ethers version 6 then you have to remove utils. you can directly use

`ethers.parseEther("")`

instead of `ethers.utils.parseEther()`